# sms applcation via C# and sms gateway

Tags: c#, sms-gateway

I suppose to develop sms application(basically send\receive) using c# 4.0.In this i wish to use NOKIA 6630 phone as the GSM moderm.i have two problems here.
1)could any one tell me a better free sms gateway for this?
2)is nokia 6630 have gsm mordem?.
i m heavily appreciated with your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what do you mean by free sms gateway here when you are using your phone.

6630 has a modem. So you can use it. If you can have PC suite (or Ovi suite) in your pc, you should visit these links:

http://www.emant.com/index.php?tid=681002

http://www.forum.nokia.com/info/sw.nokia.com/id/bd896b31-92ba-4624-aa9d-ebf732e7cc0d/Nokia_PC_Suite_Connectivity_API_1_1.html

If you do not want PC Suite and want to develop stand alone application, you need to send sms using AT command. You need to use the SerialPort class for this.

Comment: don't i need the sms gate way if i use phone?

Comment: no need to use sms gatway if you use your phone which is connected to a pc and your sms sending application is connected to that pc

Comment: yeh exaclty .i want only that.

Comment: Then you do not need any external gateway. By the way, I suggest you searching in Google to see if anyone have already done what you are trying to do. Because this is a very common thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use your phone as a GSM Modem connect to it as if you are connecting to a Serial Port. (There are drivers which adapt USB to Serial Port. Your phone drivers might do this).

Once you manage to connect to it you can send commands such as AT+CNMI (to receive) and AT+CMGS (to send).

You might want to connect via hyperterminal to try it out first before you program it.

A good tutorial is [here.](http://www.developershome.com/sms/sendSmsByAtCommands.asp)

Comment: can i do this without having of sms gateway?

Comment: no. it just uses the same approach you use when u send an SMS from your phone by hand, just through serial port instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have one good choice to install one sms Gateway for eg. NowSMS gateway to send or receive messages. Its good one and all the related help for installation and configuration is given here     http://www.nowsms.com/doc/installing-nowsms

But one problem you had while using this gateway for receiving messages you need to change your mobile phone as not supported this feature for nowsms gateway.